# Why isn't CodeIgniter's form validation not validating anything?

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

Because of the bug in AngularJS, I need more than ever to make CodeIgniter validate my registration form.

I have done everything I can think of to troubleshoot this problem. Maybe it just needs a different set of eyes? Or maybe someone has dealt with this before?

```
    public function register_validation() {

        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username',
            'required|trim|is_unique[users.username]|max_length[32]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password',
            'required|trim|min_length[6]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email',
            'required|trim|valid_email|is_unique[users.email]');

        if($this->form_validation->run()) {
            echo "Pass!";
        } else {
            echo "NOPE!";
            $this->load->view('home');
        }

    }
```

Comment: what about range with **max_length** ?

Comment: My mistake I did catch that in my files, but not here I guess. I shall fix that. It doesn't affect my situation unfortunately. I only wish it was that simple haha.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Password',
            'required|trim|min_length[6]');
```

Should be:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password',
            'required|trim|min_length[6]');
```

You used `username` twice. You should change your `run()` check to:

```
if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE))
{
    echo "NOPE!";
    $this->load->view('home');
}
else
{
    echo "Pass!";
}
```

Comment: I have used both ways. Ultimately this is better practice than what I have used, but it doesn't change the fact that form_validation doesn't seem to be returning any errors ever.

Answer (score 0):

this line is correct

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username',
        'required|trim|is_unique[users.username]|max_length');
```

first username is your field name and second one is which show in the error.

but this line

```
this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Password',
        'required|trim|min_length[6]');
```

here you used username name which is already validating instead of username you used password

there are many ways for applying conditions

first one is

```
if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)) {
    $this->load->view('home');
} else {
    echo "Pass!";
}
```

second one is

```
if($this->form_validation->run() != FALSE) {
     echo "Pass!";
} else {
     $this->load->view('home');
}
```

Comment: Well thank you for catching that, but the password wasn't my biggest concern. It's mainly checking to see if the user exists. As I recall, CodeIgniter doesn't require you to create a separate function because of `is_unique[]`.

Comment: You can create separate function for validating username but this is built-in function given by codeigniter. I personaly think that this is the best option you have to use built-in codeigniter function.

Comment: That is what I am trying to do. But it will not run.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
    if($this->form_validation->run()) {
```

to

```
    if($this->form_validation->run($this)) {
```